# How do i reuse the expression from HtmlHelper.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my cshtml file i have the following call

```
@foreach( var EducationPlan in Model.Fields) {
    @HtmlHelper.EditorFor(m => EducationPlan, "ViewFieldInputWithHidden")
}
```

and in ViewFieldInputWithHidden.cshtml i have

```
@HtmlHelper.TextBox(Model.MemberName, Model.Value, Model.HtmlAttributes)
@HtmlHelper.Hidden(Model.MemberName, Model.Value, new { id = Model.MemberName + "_Hidden" })
```

This gives me, with unimportant stuff removed

```
<input id="EducationPlan_ResponsiblePerson" name="EducationPlan.ResponsiblePerson" type="text">
<input id="ResponsiblePerson_Hidden" name="EducationPlan.ResponsiblePerson" type="hidden">
```

Is there any way to emulate/use the same value as the TextBox uses to get the "EducationPlan" string with me when i write the id? Or is there, even better, just a way to append the "_Hidden" to the id.

I found the solution and i'm leaving it here for other who runs into the same problem.

Replacing the hidden with the following code helped:

```
@Html.Hidden(Model.MemberName, Model.Value, new { id = Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(Model.MemberName) + "_Hidden" })
```

So, basically the TemplateInfo class saves the expression in some way.

Comment: You want to get the string `EducationPlan`?

Comment: Yes, more exactly the string used in the Linq-expression in my cshtml, the same way as HtmlHelper.TextBox does it.

Comment: Did you try `@typeof(Model).Name`?

Comment: EducationPlan isn't the type of the fields, it's the name of the variable in a foreach. I have updated the question to reflect this better, thanks for the comment as it helped me improve my question.